# Update Syntax with joins

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to update a column only with the matched condition.

```
update table1 set col=Match
where id in(select id from
table1,table2 where table1.id=table2.id);
```

It says sql command not properly ended.

Comment: can you please update your answer with the actual output of the error

Comment: the error i get is invalid identifier.

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00904: "M1": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: 00904 means you probably have a typo for one of your table or column names. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00904.php

Comment: There's no M1 in your query, so - how can it raise an error? If you are setting col to be `Match`, then enclose it into single quotes, i.e. `col = 'Match'`. It would help if you posted accurate information, not fabricated ones.

Comment: Update table1 
set criteria='M1' 
where id =(select *  FROM  table1 a,table2 b
where a.id=b.id);

Comment: it still gives an error as too many values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which shows what to do (at least, that's what I understood, based on the question and comments you posted).

Test case first:

```
SQL> create table table1 (id number, criteria varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create table table2 (id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into table1 (id)
  2    select 1 from dual union all
  3    select 2 from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> insert into table2 (id)
  2    select 1 from dual;

1 row created.
```

As you can see, both tables share `ID = 1` so we'd expect its `table1.criteria` to be modified.

Your query:

```
SQL> update table1 set
  2    criteria = 'M1'
  3  where id in (select a.id
  4               from table1 a join table2 b on a.id = b.id
  5              );

1 row updated.

SQL> -- Result
SQL> select * From table1;

        ID CRITERIA
---------- ----------
         1 M1
         2
```

Alternatively:

```
SQL> update table1 a set
  2    a.criteria = 'M2'
  3  where exists (select null
  4                from table2 b
  5                where b.id = a.id
  6               );

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From table1;

        ID CRITERIA
---------- ----------
         1 M2
         2
```

See if it helps.

Comment: Update table1 set criteria='M3' where criteria is null and col1 in (select sys.utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.COl1, b.COl1) as similarity from table1 a,table2 b where sys.utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.COl1, b.COl1) >= 80);

Comment: I get a error message as SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: I am trying to do a partial match in two different tables. the criteria column is already satisified with some values with some other condition, but i want to take the empty (null values) to do the matching. Could you pls help me with this